# Is Tensorflow RNN implements Elman network fully?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

## Q: Is Tensorflow RNN implemented to ouput Elman Network's hidden state?

[image]
[image]

```
cells  = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(4) 
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cells, etc...)
```

I'm quiet new to TF's RNN and curious about meaning of outputs, and state.
I'm following stanford's tensorflow tutorial but there seems no detailed explanation so I'm asking here.
After testing, I think `state` is hidden state after sequence calculation and `outputs` is array of hidden states after each time steps.

so I want to make it clear. outputs and state are just hidden state vectors so to fully implement Elman network, I have to make V matrix in the picture and do matrix multiplication again. am I correct?

Comment: and why is there RNNCell output_size and state_size property? what's the difference

Comment: Right, there's no matrix multiply on the output. And for BasicRNNCell state size and output size are the same (this is not true e.g. for the LSTM cells).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking what the output of a intermediate state and output is.

From what I understand, the state would be intermediate output after a convolution / sequence calculation and is hidden, so your understanding is in the right direction.

Output may vary as how you decide to implement your network model, but on a general basis, it is an array where any operation (convolution, sequence calc etc) has been applied after which activation & downsampling/pooling has been applied, to concentrate on identifiable features across that layer.

From Colah's blog ( http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/ ):

Finally, we need to decide what we’re going to output. This output will be based on our cell state, but will be a filtered version. First, we run a sigmoid layer which decides what parts of the cell state we’re going to output. Then, we put the cell state through tanhtanh (to push the values to be between −1−1 and 11) and multiply it by the output of the sigmoid gate, so that we only output the parts we decided to.

For the language model example, since it just saw a subject, it might want to output information relevant to a verb, in case that’s what is coming next. For example, it might output whether the subject is singular or plural, so that we know what form a verb should be conjugated into if that’s what follows next.

Hope this helps.
Thank you